# Conceptual issue: Verifying that two users are present

Tags: intranet

I'm a programmer who is about to release an intranet site where apprentices can rate their educators and vice versa. Currently the system is working as planned, however HR wants some way to verify that the users are OK with their ratings. If not, they should be able to unlock their ratings so that the other person has to re-do the rating.

Unfortunately, HR also wants to reduce the amount of logins that these users have to endure. In the worst case scenario, users have to:

- Log in to rate the educator/apprentice
- Log in to unlock the rating
- Log in to rate the educator/apprentice again
- And so on...

The user who fills the rating has to be user A, while the user who unlocks or confirms the rating has to be user B. User A can also unlock the rating if they have a correction.

This process has to be done twice - once for the educator, once for the apprentice.

There is usually only one workstation present (factory environment).

**Possible solution:**

My suggestion is a kind of meeting workflow. One user logs in, clicks a button in the appraisal and the workflow starts. The other user is prompted to log in. This starts a kind of "double session" with both users logged in at the same time. This is a way to verify that both of them are present in a meeting.

This process could be used for multiple ratings at the same time, guiding the users through the process one by one.

*HR wants both of them to meet and discuss their ratings.*

Are there any security and/or best practice concerns that I should be aware of? The system has to be ready on the first of August, so I'm really hoping to solve this issue as easily as possible. Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my idea of logging in two users at the same time wasn't so bad. At first, a regular user logs in and launches the meeting mode. In order to verify that the other user is present, this second user logs in. Both user's data is now stored in the session and the meeting workflow launches, guiding both of them through their appraisals. When the last appraisal is finished, the second user is logged out.

This question is solved.